# C - Printing binary for a given character

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am learning C and part of my exercise is dealing with bitwise operators. I am trying to create a function that prints out a 2's complement for a char input.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void  find_binary(char ch) {

        long bit_index = 0;
        unsigned long sz = sizeof(ch)*8-1;
        for (bit_index = 0; bit_index <= sz; ++bit_index) {
                int bit = (1 << bit_index) & ch;
                printf("%d", bit);
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Here is the output: `0008032640` when I input `'h'`.

Why is this printing integers other than 0 and 1?

Comment: Because you are printing `int`s that have values other than `0` or `1`.

Comment: Hmm, so is it not because of a logical error?

Comment: You're printing the value of each bit as an int instead of just 1 or 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression

```
int bit = (1 << bit_index) & ch;
```

produces a zero or a power of two with the corresponding bit set. To bring it into the 0..1 range, either shift `ch` right and mask with `1`, or convert your expression as follows:

```
int bit = ((1 << bit_index) & ch) != 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void  find_binary( char ch ) 
{
    for ( int i = CHAR_BIT; i != 0; )
    {
        int bit = ( 1 << --i & ch ) != 0;
        printf( "%d", bit );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    find_binary( 'A' );

    return 0;
}
```